# Reducing Calls to Firebase vs Reducing Data Redundancy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently developing an app with a Chat Feature and was wondering if I should prioritize in minimizing the calls to the DB or minimize the data redundancy in the DB.

---

*Sample DB structure*

For the users part:

```
users/
  active/
    $uid/ (Firebase Auth generated)
      username: string
      userPhotoUrl: string
```

For the chat messages part:

```
messages/
  chatRooms/
    $chatRoomId/
      dateCreated: timestamp
      title: string

  chatMessages/
    $chatRoomId/
      $messageId/
        createdAt: timestamp
        uid: string
        message: string
```

As seen in the DB structure, if I retrieve the chat objects (`messageId`) I'd only be able to retrieve `createdAt`, `uid`, `message`. This is working fine, however, I would also need the `username` and `userPhotoUrl` in order to show the desired data on the client side.

***Approach***: A flow to get the data I need is to make two calls to the DB, one is to get the data from `chatMessages` node and the other on the `users` node.

There are two scenarios where I would need these data:

1. Retrieving multiple chat messages (initially and every time the user decides to view older messages).
2. A new chat message is saved to the DB.

---

For the *first scenario*, what I would have to do is to first retrieve the list of `chatMessages`, upon getting them successfully, I would then need to make a call to DB to get the user details (`username`, `userPhotoUrl`) for each chat message -- in order to avoid redundancy of calls as well, I'm saving each user details locally (in SharedPrefs), so that if it already exists, I would just get it immediately.

- *Pros*: Minimizes data redundancy in Firebase DB, which saves space.
- *Cons*: This involves a lot of API calls and would increase the time to actually be able to display the chat messages.

Possible workaround to make things simpler is to have a `username` and `userPhotoUrl` for each chat message. E.g.:

```
$messageId/
  createdAt: timestamp
  uid: string
  username: string
  userPhotoUrl: string
  message: string
```

- *Pros*: Easier retrieval since it would just be a single call.
- *Cons*: Data redundancy would be too much.

For the *second scenario*, I would have to do the same approach every time I detect a child is added to the `$chatRoomId`. Same pros and cons.

---

I understand that data redundancy in NoSQL DB is fine, but for a chat app that would contain a lot of messages, and where the message is the data that could contain redundant data, I think it would be quite heavy stored data wise.

Question is, am I right to aim for reducing the data redundancy, trading a lot of API calls in turn? If anyone could suggest a better approach that I might be missing, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: There is no simple right or wrong here. Data duplication is the key to faster reads, not just in NoSQL but in general. Any time you add a cache, you're duplicating data in favor of faster read performance. In return you have a more complex update and higher storage/memory usage. That said: extra calls in Firebase don't have to be expensive. How much duplication-vs-extra-calls is optimal depends on your needs and your willingness to let go of the Single Point of Definition mindset, it is thus very subjective.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Puf! We did thought as much, guess we just have to decide if we're going for easier retrieval or saving DB space.

Comment: I find that my reading code gets *drastically* simpler if I duplicate data. But of course the writing code gets more complex at the same time. It's a trade-off between these two and your needs that determines the optimal solution for your app.